# The issue is about MPAndroidChart-markerview

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

My project uses the lib mpandroidchart,I need the markerview,so I custom the my markerview it has two textview,the one shows xAxis value and another shows yAxis value.my xAxis is date of string type,for example "2016-4-29",my yAxis is the value of float.the question is the xAxis value can't show at the markerview like the "2016-4-29".but it show the value for "1,2,3......",how can I show my xAxis value of String type?

my code :

```
@Override
public void refreshContent(Entry e, Highlight highlight) {
    if (e instanceof CandleEntry) {
        CandleEntry ce = (CandleEntry) e;
        mNetValue.setText("净值：" + Utils.formatNumber(ce.getHigh(), 4, true));
    } else {
        mDate.setText(Utils.formatNumber(e.getXIndex(), 2, true));
        mNetValue.setText("净值："+Utils.formatNumber(e.getVal(), 4, true));  
        //mZhangDie.setText("涨跌幅");
    }

}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xshdP.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get xVals value for Entry e, you should use xVals.get(e.getXIndex())

So in your code :

```
mDate.setText(xVals.get(e.getXIndex()));
```

Comment: Thanks very muck , it works . And if I want my MarkerView  add a textview to show the third value, neither xAxis value nor yAxis value. and the third value in the arraylist<String> , how I can show the third value in my markerview? Thanks advance!